# Refresh a div content every time interval in grails

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do you do that so that a `div` refreshes say every 5 seconds automatically or if there are changes in the database. with ajax? or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Set an interval on 5000 that runs a function update div.
checkout following link:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Let's say you have a div with id of `my_div` and you want refresh it's content every 5 seconds by requesting from `my_page.php`.

Client-Side JavaScript Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="my_div"></div>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var refresh_time = 5000;

  /** To make sure that program will execute when everything loaded in page. **/
  window.onload = function(){

    /** setInterval() will calls my_div_update() function in refresh times. **/
    setInterval(function(){my_div_update();}, refresh_time);

  }

  /** Uses Ajax request to update my_div content. **/
  function my_div_update()
    {
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      /** To make sure everything is ok on the way. **/
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","my_page.php");
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Server-Side PHP Code:

```
<?php echo date('h:i:s - A'); ?>
```

Comment: this works but is this good? i mean it just refreshes every 5s. Is there some kind of code for checking if there are changes in the DB then it will refresh

Comment: In http world everything begins with a request, so you "must" send a request to server-page to see changes.

Comment: can you guide me in the right direction on how to do that? or give me a tutorial?